# C# Provide no generic value to T interface in method... Ex: "MyMethod<IHello<>>()"

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is a way to make method No.1 work... I do not like method No.2 :D

Call for Method No.1

```
instance.GetInterfaceGenericValueType<IHello<>>();
```

Call for Method No.2

```
instance.GetInterfaceGenericValueType(typeof(IHello<>));
```

Implementation for No2.

```
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfaceGenericValueType(this Type type, Type interfaceType)
    {
        return type.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(a => a.IsGenericType && a.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType)
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetGenericArguments());
    }
```

-------Edited Post Below---------

Implementation for No.1

```
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfaceGenericValueType<T>(this Type type)
    {
        return type.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(a => a.IsGenericType && a.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(T))
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetGenericArguments());
    }
```

The thing that is weird for me is... Implementation No.1 will never work, because type T cannot be unknown Generic -> 'Hello<>'. But typeof(Hello<>) works it! can be unknown generic.

Comment: IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfaceGenericValueType<T>(this Type type) { var interfaceType = typeof(T); // etc.. }

Comment: Sorry I badly explain, the problem is not the method its the call... I have the 2 methods implemented.
 GetInterfaceGenericValueType<T>(this Type type)  and
 GetInterfaceGenericValueType(this Type type) 

the problem is I am not allow to call Method<IHello<>>(), it say IHello must have a type. I do not like having to do typeof(IHello<>).

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can do what you want. C# generics require all arguments to be set.

Comment: Ah ok! That is weird a bit. Can't have empty Bracket there... but in the typeof() its ok???

Comment: @SebastienLachapelle its not really weird. Consider `Foo<T>(T instance)` and now pass `Foo<IHello<>>(?)`. What is the type of instance? The type `IHello<>` doesn't really exist, it is a meta-type for creating concrete types.